# Is there a way to check if next token is END?

Tags: java, bychan

**I'm using the bychan library and this question mainly surrounds it.**

I just checked out the [minilang](https://github.com/atorstling/bychan/blob/master/src/test/java/org/bychan/core/langs/minilang/StatementNode.java) example and read through the code. When I saw the `StatementNode`, I was struggling to find a way to add an ending semicolon for conventional purpose. In that example, the `;` is used to separate statements, but there isn't a way to end a script with the last statement ending with a `;` because the parser isn't able to parse the end and would result in:

```
'Premature end reached' @  position ..., current lexeme is END ...
```

Is there a way to check whether the next token is the `END` or is what I'm thinking incorrect and looking ahead isn't the right thing to do and that there are other ways?

I did try `parser.nextIs(EndToken.get())` before, but the IDE simply says `no instance(s) of type variable(s) N exist so that EndToken<N> conforms to TokenKey`

I may not be that advance in Java to figure out a solution. :(

from: https://github.com/atorstling/bychan/issues/37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an omission. The core parser `PrattParser`has a `peek()` function to get the next token and you can compare it to any token type. You would use that as `peek().getToken().equals(EndToken.get())`.

The parser interface for the dynamic package, `UserParserCallback`, has another interface for the same thing: `nextIs(TokenKey)`. The idea was to create a more typesafe equality check than javas builtin `equals`. The equality type was called `TokenKey`.

Now you ran into the problem that the static tokens, such as `EndToken`, didn't have any `TokenKey`s. The fix for issue 37 resolved this.

So now you can call `parser.nextIs(EndToken.get().getKey())`. For an example, see [ReadmeExamples::statements](https://github.com/atorstling/bychan/blob/master/src/test/java/org/bychan/core/examples/ReadmeExamples.java#L194).

`